How to Get Console Font Size from Script?

I opened PowerShell console window, then checked the font size in properties is 16.
How do I get that via script?
I looking for $Host.UI.RawUI not in there.
Looking the registry:
(Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe").FontSize

the value is as hex 1c0011 as dec 1835025.
I don't know yet what's this and how it relates to 16.
Using module WindowsConsoleFonts (Get-ConsoleFont).Size, the output is 65x24. It's window size, not font size.
In essence, I want to get font size through a script whose results are the same as in the PowerShell properties.
Thanks.
